# How to invoke my post method when I'm changing dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, controller, view

I'm very new to MVC and Javascript so please be patient with me, I'm working on small application and I came to part when I need to select something from dropdown list and based on that selection I need to redirect user to another View, I also need to determine somehow where I should redirect user, so that is reason why I tried to pass parameter also ( database ID  to my post method) but unfortunatelly this is not working, in section below I will post my code:

Method which is sending data to my DropDownList :

```
 public ActionResult ShowArticleGroup()
 {
    List<ArticleGroup> articlesGroups = GroupsController.GetAllGroups();


    ViewBag.articlesGroups = articlesGroups;
    return View(articlesGroups);

 }




[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowArticleGroup(string id)
{
   //Here I wanted to take ID of selected Group and because there will be allways 3 Groups  I can do if else and Redirect by ID
   if(id =="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002")
   {
      return RedirectToAction("Create","Article");
   }
   return RedirectToAction("Create", "Article");
 }
```

And my VIEW - there is only one control on the view : just one dropdown, and based on selection I should be redirected to another view, and I wanted here to take ID of selected group and by that I wanted to redirect user to appropiate view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Model.ArticleGroup>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add new article";
}
<h3 style="text-align:center">Choose article group</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
            @Html.DropDownList("Group", new SelectList(ViewBag.articlesGroups, "GroupID", "GroupTitle.Name"), null, new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/Articles/ShowArticleGroup/' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" })
        </div>

    </div>

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, usage of `location.href` on `DropDownList` seems wrong here:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Group", new SelectList(ViewBag.articlesGroups, "GroupID", "GroupTitle.Name"), null, 
 new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/Articles/ShowArticleGroup/' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" })
```

AFAIK, [`location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) used for redirect to another page using **HTTP GET**, hence it will try to call first `ShowArticleGroup` action method without parameter, and the URL parameter simply ignored since given URL parameter only exist in **POST**.

To submit the form with `DropDownList`, you need to handle `change` event triggering POST into controller action method:

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Group").change(function() {
            var groupId = $("#Group").val();
            $.post('@Url.Action("ShowArticleGroup", "ControllerName")', { id: groupId }, function (response, status) {
                 // response handling (optional)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**DropDownList**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Group", new SelectList(ViewBag.articlesGroups, "GroupID", "GroupTitle.Name"), null)
```

I recommend you using strongly-typed `DropDownListFor` with binding to a viewmodel approach if you want to pass viewmodel contents during form submit.

NB: [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) is shorthand version of `$.ajax` which uses POST submit method as default.

Related issues:

[Autopost back in mvc drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729171/autopost-back-in-mvc-drop-down-list)

[MVC 4 postback on Dropdownlist change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933115/mvc-4-postback-on-dropdownlist-change)