# How to display in my view the folders corresponding to my selection in a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner and I am trying to write an application in C#.

I would like to filter through a `DropDownList` that uses an `Enum`.
Can someone tell me how I have to proceed in my controller so that when I select `Complete` in my view, it only displays the complete files?

This is what my class looks like:

```
namespace Client.Models
{
    public enum StadeProg1
    {
        Complet, Incomplet
    }
    public class Programmes1
    {
        public int Programmes1Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime MiseEnVenteDateProg { get; set; }
        public StadeProg1? StadeProg { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Commentaire> Commentaire { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DocSource> DocSource { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is what is in my sight:

```
<p>
    @Html.DropDownList("Etat", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(StadeProg1)), "Etat", new { @class = "form-control" })
</p>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Could this post help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933115/mvc-4-postback-on-dropdownlist-change

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,

I have succeeded with this code in my `controller`:

```
   ViewBag.Etat = Etat;
        if (Etat.HasValue)
        {
            if (Etat == StadeProg1.Complet)
                programmes1 = programmes1.Where(p => 
   p.StadeProg==StadeProg1.Complet);
            else
                programmes1 = programmes1.Where(p => 
   p.StadeProg==StadeProg1.Incomplet);

        }
```

I also change my `view`:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Programmes1", FormMethod.Get, new { id 
    = "filterForm" }))
    {

    <p>
    @Html.DropDownList("Etat", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(StadeProg1)), 
    "Etat",
     new { @class = "form-control", onchange = 
     "document.getElementById('filterForm').submit();" })
     </p>
     }
```

I leave what I have done in case it could help another person. Even though I'm sure he has a much better way to do it.